# When running `ember test`, execution hangs at `Built project successfully. Stored in ". . .`

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've googled around for an answer but have yet to turn up anything of use. Does anyone know why attempts to run `ember test` at best result in a message that reads:

`Built project successfully. Stored in "/Users/.../tmp/class-tests_dist-H42JePnK.tmp".`

Answer (score 1):

If your tests won't run at all, here are a few things to look for:

1. Check for a testem.js file. It is essential and contains the instructions and configurations that the Ember CLI needs. Deleting it will cause your app to build and 0 tests to run.
2. Check to make sure your testem.js file is valid/complete. You can test this by doing `ember init` and then choosing option d (diff) to see what is different between your app and a brand new app.
3. Your tests are also available in the normal browser. Go to `http://localhost:4200/tests` and see what happens there. Perhaps it will give some clues.
4. Similar to above, try `ember test --server` and see if you get different results.
5. Create a fresh app with `ember new` and try doing `ember test`. It can sometimes be easier to compare a fresh app instead of doing the `ember init` diffing.
6. Try switching the browser you are using for testing (unlikely to be the problem in this case, but sometimes works). For example, run the tests with headless Chrome instead of PhantomJS. The most recent release of the Ember ClI has the testem configuration that you need to try headless Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for offering such an in-depth answer. Unfortunately, none of your suggestions seem to work in my case. I was able to verify that, running the test within a new project functions as expected, though.

Comment: You mentioned that dying after the build was best case scenario. What happened the other times? What did you see when you visited /tests?